# Chebiyshev Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

In proving the Chebyshev inequality in Probability theory an important step is to observe that:

$P((|x-E(x)|≥a))=P(|x-E(x)|^2≥a^2)$.

It is assumed that X has a moment of order 2.
Can somebody help me to understand why the equality holds?
I got an other question: why it is important to take the absolute value of X at the Markov and Chebyshhev inequalities?

Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

As $|X-E(X)|$ and $a$ are positive, $|X-E(X)|\geq a\Leftrightarrow (|X-E(X)|)^2\geq a^2$ because the square function is increasing. So the probabilities of these two events are equal.

There is an absolute value because you need the positivity in the proof of the Markov inequality, and the Chebitchev inequality is just a corrolary of the Markov inequality.

Comment: i understand the inequality you are refering to, but i dont understand the conclusion, it was actually my question: Why the probabilities of the two events coincide ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ivo The probabilities of the events coincide because they are the *same* event. $$\{x: \lvert{x-\mu}\rvert\geqslant a\}\quad=\quad\{x:\lvert{x-\mu}\rvert^2\geqslant a^2\}$$